# Get image from program interacting with graphics card directly?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, image-processing

I am trying to use Pillow with Python on Windows 10 to take screenshots of an application. This application is interacting directly with the graphics card, so instead of getting images inside the program, it returns black images. How can I get a screenshot from the graphics being served by this application.

Here are different methods I've tried with PIL imports of course.

```
im=ImageGrab.grab()
ImageGrab.grab_to_file('im.png')

hwnd = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
wDC = win32gui.GetWindowDC(hwnd)
dcObj=win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(wDC)
cDC=dcObj.CreateCompatibleDC()
dataBitMap = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
dataBitMap.CreateCompatibleBitmap(dcObj, w, h)
cDC.SelectObject(dataBitMap)
cDC.BitBlt((0,0),(w, h) , dcObj, (0,0), win32con.SRCCOPY)
dataBitMap.SaveBitmapFile(cDC, 'tmp.bmp')
# Free Resources
dcObj.DeleteDC()
cDC.DeleteDC()
win32gui.ReleaseDC(hwnd, wDC)
win32gui.DeleteObject(dataBitMap.GetHandle())
```